# I'm not able to access my db via IP on one network but I can access it on a different network

Tags: home-networking, ip-address

I'm trying to access my db at 2##.##.##.### I'm not able to access it when I'm on my home network but I can access it via my office's network. When i use a VPN, I can access the db though. Can someone explain how will i be able to access the db like I'm on other networks. I'll appreciate the BTS of why it shouldn't be working.

A bit more context: I guess my network is a pretty simple one. The network topology is G-2425G-A. A NOKIA router that I guess has a modem and an AP that I got from my ISP. There aren't any firewall placements, atleast I didn't make any changes to the default configurations.